# Fetch API as readable stream

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Given a description in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams):

> As a JavaScript developer, programmatically reading and manipulating
> streams of data received over the network, **chunk by chunk**, is very
> useful!

Given an [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams#reading_the_stream):

> Now you've got your reader attached, you can read data chunks out of
> the stream using the ReadableStreamDefaultReader.read()

I can't clearly understand if we use *fetch('./tortoise.png')* first does it mean it first of all download the whole image and only *then* we can attach a reader to it to recive data *chunk by chunk*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch` promise resolves before you get all the data, that's why you have to usually call `response.json()`. `json()` function waits for the data to load before it can parse it

This code on the other hand:

```
fetch('./tortoise.png')
  .then((response) => response.body)
  .then((body) => {
    const reader = body.getReader();
    // …
  });
```

won't wait for the data to finish loading before creating the reader